# What property in ThemeData define icons color?

Tags: flutter

Is icon color defined by iconTheme in ThemeDada? For instance, I defined it the way like this

```
  darkTheme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
    primaryColor: Color(0xff64ffda),
    iconTheme: IconThemeData(
      color: Colors.pink,
    ),
  ),
```

But the icon color is white in the folowing example for dark theme mode

```
Row(
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
  children: [
    Icon(
      Icons.save,
    ),
  ],
),
```

Comment: is the dark mode enabled on the phone?

Comment: @OMiShah the dark theme enabled by the app itself

Comment: and how exactly have you enabled it? @rozerro

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59464690/5882307

Comment: @OMiShah the way lile that

Answer (score 0):

```
Row(
 mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
children: [
 Icon(
   Icons.save,
   color: Theme.of(context).iconTheme.color
  ),
 ],
),
```

This Code will use your IconColor